# Server-side pagination with AngularJS and UIBootstrap

Tags: angularjs, jakarta-ee, server-side, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a question about the server-side pagination with AngularJS and UIBootstrap.
I need to manipulate the HTTP Header "Content-Range", because on the Server are 20 items by default. For example when I add a new item (person) on the person page, leave the page and go back to the person page, the pagination have 20 items and the pagination 4 sites again. I think because the Content-Range shows always the same size. The output of Content-Range is "Content-Range: count 0 - 19 / 20"

In the backend I have Java Annotations where I can access on the value.

```
@Path("/persons")
...
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getAll(
@ApiParam(value = "Offset", required = false, defaultValue = "0") @QueryParam("offset") Optional<Integer> offset,
@ApiParam(value = "Size", required = false, defaultValue = "20") @QueryParam("size") Optional<Integer> size)...
```

My question is, how can I access or change the offset value? I've tried the $http-Service but the only what I get from the Server are the data as an Array.

Comment: When I call http://localhost:8080/persons/?offset=1&size=20 then I get the data in JSON Format.

Comment: After adding a new person refresh your person list page. Call your "/person" rest api again.

Comment: I know what you mean, but the problem is, when you switch on other sites and go back to the person site the new items aren't there and that might not be. I only need the "offset"-Parameter what you can see in my code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the querystring parameters on `$http` service

```
$http({
      url: '/person',
      method: 'GET',
      params: {offset:1, size: 15}
});
```